# How to pass Json to AZ Login Github Action?

Tags: json, azure, environment-variables, github-actions

I've seen some related questions and answers, but none that quite address what I'm looking for.

I am setting up a Github Actions workflow that uses a more limited Service Principal to login to Azure (these initial credentials are stored in the Github Actions secrets GUI), then queries Azure KeyVault to get the credentials for a Project Contributor Service Principal that actually does things with our Azure subscription.

It looks something like this:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ["prod"]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  
  azure_login_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      
      - name: 'Checkout source code'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Login to Azure with Login Service Principal
        uses: Azure/login@v1
        with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURELOGINSP }}
     
      - name: Get Project Contributor SP Key Vault Secret
        id: "query_key_vault_for_secret"
        run:
            project_sp_client_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Project-SP-Client-ID" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            project_sp_secret_value=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Project-SP-SECRET-VALUE" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            subscription_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Subscription-ID" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            tenant_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Tenant-ID" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            
            project_sp_creds_json=$(cat <<EOF
               {'client-id':'$project_sp_client_id',
                'client-secret':'$project_sp_secret_value',
                'subscription-id':'$subscription_id',
                'tenant-id':'$tenant_id'}
            EOF
            )

            # also tried
            # project_sp_creds_json="{'client-id':'$project_sp_client_id','client-secret':'$project_sp_secret_value','subscription-id':'$subscription_id','tenant-id':'$tenant_id'}"

            echo "PROJECTSPCREDSJSON=$project_sp_creds_json" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
           

      - name: Re-Login to Azure using Project SP
        uses: Azure/login@v1
        with:
            creds: ${{ steps.query_key_vault_for_secret.output.PROJECTSPCREDSJSON }}
```

I get json parsing errors when I use this code, such as:

```
Error: Login failed with Error: Content is not a valid JSON object.  
Double check if the 'auth-type' is correct. Refer to  
https://github.com/Azure/login#readme for more information.
```

or

```
Invalid format ' 'client-id': '***', '
```

How might I fix my json, or the way I send output to $GITHUB_OUTPUT, etc, to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around solution that doesn't involve using json at all, but I'm still very much interested if I can use the `Azure/login` Github Action.

By adding this native `az login` code to the end of the KeyVault query step (which works fine), I can persistently login to the Project Contributor Service Principal, and then omit the Login Step entirely:

```bash
az login --service-principal -u $project_sp_client_id -p $project_sp_secret_value --tenant $tenant_id
```

In total, this looks like:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ["prod"]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  
  azure_login_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      
      - name: 'Checkout source code'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Login to Azure with Login Service Principal
        uses: Azure/login@v1
        with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURELOGINSP }}
     
      - name: Get Project Contributor SP Key Vault Secret, then Login again
        id: "query_key_vault_and_login_to_project_sp"
        uses: azure/cli@v2
        with:
          azcliversion: 2.30.0
          inlinescript: |

            project_sp_client_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Project-SP-Client-ID" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            project_sp_secret_value=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Project-SP-SECRET-VALUE" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            # subscription_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Subscription-ID" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv) # unnecessary
            tenant_id=$(az keyvault secret show --name "Tenant-ID" --vault-name "MyVault" --query value -o tsv)
            
            az login --service-principal -u $project_sp_client_id -p $project_sp_secret_value --tenant $tenant_id
```